# Why do I get a connection error although the call file is the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

My issue as as followings, I am running a WebSocket Server that I wrote in Node.js and is ran around an environment built primarily with Laravel. In order to utilize the `.env` file just like Laravel I am using the `dotenv` package.

I noticed something that me appeared very strange. But before I can explain that, let me give you a quick folder structure typical for Laravel with my node addition:

```
htdocs
 - app
 - node  
     - RunServer.js
     - db.js
     ....  
 - resources  
 ....
```

**My Observation**

When I am in the `htdocs` folder and I run `node node/RunServer.js`, I get the following error:

```
/var/www/html/bigriss/node/db.js:16
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:3306 
....
```

While `cd node; node RunServer.js` does not give an error and the server begins to run as expected. The db.js file looks as follows:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
}).connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Clearly the issue has to do with `dotenv` but I am unsure why the path in the file changes (giving me different process.env output) even though both `node node/RunServer.js` and `cd node; node RunServer.js` run the exact same thing. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the path specified in dotenv.config({path:...}) its being resolved relative to the current working directory (cwd). Therefore the result will be different if node is run on different directories.